# findViewById returning null in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am replacing the existing fragment with new fragment and i am able to see my view but while setting on click listener on the button it returns null . I get the following exception :

```
?:??: W/?(?): java.lang.NullPointerException
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.biggu.shopsavvy.fragments.xxxxxxxx.onCreateView(xxxxxx.java:34)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
?:??: W/?(?):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
?:??: W/?(?):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
?:??: W/?(?):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
?:??: W/?(?):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have no clue what is happening ?

The code on OnCreateView :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capture_card_phone_number, container, false);
        mPhone = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        Button next = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.capture_phone_next);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        // next.setEnabled(false);

        return view;
```

I have also imported com.big.xxxxxxx.R

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I have already cleaned and regenerated R.java.

Comment: plz add the code in the method onCreateView() , specialy in the line 34 of your xxxxx.java class , and add the xml layout too for your fragment

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I have inflated the view in OnCreateView of the fragment that is why i am able to view the fragment but unable to set any kind of listeners since my button seems to be null (even though i can see the button )

Comment: i know , but add your code ans specialy what i 've told you in my first comment, if not , i can't help you  , i should see the code to detect where is the problem of your nullpointer , may be the id of your button , may be the R.java i think you have imported android.R and not your com.yourpackage.R

Comment: But your button is in fragment view or activity view? It is in capture_card_phone_number layout?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 

    savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capture_card_phone_number, container, false);
            mPhone = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            Button next = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.capture_phone_next);
            next.setOnClickListener(this);


            return view;
```

You have to call findViewById on your view - not on your activity.

Comment: is there a reason that you use findviewbyid on the activity in the activity but on the view in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in onCreateView the View of Fragment is not created yet, so it is returning null. Try to do it in onResume and it will return you the view:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mPhone = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
    Button next = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.capture_phone_next);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);   
}
```