# Fragment onSaveInstanceState crashing app on screen rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an app with fragments. One of the fragments asks the user to enter team names in 2 text fields. I want to save the names in the onSaveInstanceState . This works however when I move to another fragment and rotate the screen I get the error below which points towards the edittext fields I am trying to save. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm getting a NullPointerException but i'm not sure why. Thanks!

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Error points to,

EditText teamAname = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.teamAname);

```
//Save data
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setUserVisibleHint(false);

    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamATry", TeamATry);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBTry", TeamBTry);
    EditText teamAname = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.teamAname);
    teamAname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    String teamAnametext = teamAname.getText().toString();
    EditText teamBname = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.teamBname);
    teamBname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    String teamBnametext = teamBname.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamAConvert", TeamAConvert);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBConvert", TeamBConvert);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamAPenalty", TeamAPenalty);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBPenalty", TeamBPenalty);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamAScore", TeamAscore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBScore", TeamBscore);
    savedInstanceState.putString("TeamAname", teamAnametext);
    savedInstanceState.putString("TeamBname", teamBnametext);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("4", teamAnametext + "Saved");
    Log.i("4", "Match Frag Scores saved");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

OnCreateView Code

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        //Inflate rugby layout
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rugbycounter, container, false);
        this.mView = rootview;
        //This will show the menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        //Load saved state
        if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        {
            teamAnametext = savedInstanceState.getString("TeamAname");
            teamBnametext = savedInstanceState.getString("TeamBname");
            TeamATry = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamATry");
            TeamBTry = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBTry");
            TeamAConvert = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamAConvert");
            TeamBConvert = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBConvert");
            TeamAPenalty = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamAPenalty");
            TeamBPenalty = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBPenalty");
            TeamAscore = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamAScore");
            TeamBscore = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBScore");
            Log.i("Assign4", "Score values restored");
        }
        return rootview;
    }
```

Rugbycounter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--Scrollview to handle horizontal orientation-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!--Linear Layout for top section of buttons-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <!--Table layout with two columns-->
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:divider="@color/actionbar_background"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:dividerPadding="5dp">

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/teamAname"
                        android:text="@+id/teamAname"
                        android:hint="@string/hintEnterTeamA"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:freezesText="true" >
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/teamBname"
                        android:text="@+id/teamBname"
                        android:hint="@string/hintEnterTeamB"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:freezesText="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="1dp">
                    </EditText>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@+id/teamAscore"
                        android:id="@+id/teamAscore"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:freezesText="true" >
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="@+id/teamBscore"
                        android:id="@+id/teamBscore"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="50sp"
                        android:freezesText="true" >
                    </TextView>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/penalty3"
                        android:id="@+id/aPenalty"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_column="0" />

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/penalty3"
                        android:id="@+id/bPenalty"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_column="1" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/conversion2"
                        android:id="@+id/aConversion"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_column="0" />

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/conversion2"
                        android:id="@+id/bConversion"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_column="1" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/try5"
                        android:id="@+id/aTry"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_column="0" />

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/try5"
                        android:id="@+id/bTry"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_column="1" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
            <!--Linear layout to create separation between top and bottom layout-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp">

            </LinearLayout>
            <!--Linear Layout for bottom 3 buttons-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/reset"
                    android:id="@+id/resetButton"
                    android:height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

                <Button
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/SUMMARY"
                    android:id="@+id/summaryButton"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show your onCreateView() code

Comment: i've added my onCreateView code . Does that look ok?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks! could you show me an example of using a member variable for this referencing purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Move all calls of `findViewById()` to your `onCreateView()` method, and use member variables to keep a reference to your EditText fields. You shouldn't be calling `findViewById()` in the `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

In your Fragment class definition, define the EditText fields as member variables of the class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText teamAname;
    EditText teamBname;
    //.......
```

Then initialize them in onCreateView():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    //Inflate rugby layout
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rugbycounter, container, false);

    //Not needed, don't do this:
    //this.mView = rootview;

    //This will show the menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //Add this:
    teamAname = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.teamAname);
    teamBname = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.teamBname);
    teamAname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    teamBname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

    //Null check:
    if (teamAname == null) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "teamAname null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (teamBname == null) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "teamBname null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //Load saved state
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        teamAnametext = savedInstanceState.getString("TeamAname");
        teamBnametext = savedInstanceState.getString("TeamBname");
        TeamATry = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamATry");
        TeamBTry = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBTry");
        TeamAConvert = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamAConvert");
        TeamBConvert = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBConvert");
        TeamAPenalty = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamAPenalty");
        TeamBPenalty = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBPenalty");
        TeamAscore = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamAScore");
        TeamBscore = savedInstanceState.getInt("TeamBScore");
        Log.i("Assign4", "Score values restored");
    }
    return rootview;
}
```

Then, the EditText fields are ready to use in onSaveInstanceState(), so you can remove the calls to findViewById():

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setUserVisibleHint(false);

    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamATry", TeamATry);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBTry", TeamBTry);
    //EditText teamAname = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.teamAname);
    //teamAname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    String teamAnametext = teamAname.getText().toString();
    //EditText teamBname = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.teamBname);
    //teamBname.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    String teamBnametext = teamBname.getText().toString();
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamAConvert", TeamAConvert);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBConvert", TeamBConvert);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamAPenalty", TeamAPenalty);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBPenalty", TeamBPenalty);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamAScore", TeamAscore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("TeamBScore", TeamBscore);
    savedInstanceState.putString("TeamAname", teamAnametext);
    savedInstanceState.putString("TeamBname", teamBnametext);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("4", teamAnametext + "Saved");
    Log.i("4", "Match Frag Scores saved");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I tried that and the app still crashes on screen rotate with  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference  which points to String teamAnametext = teamAname.getText().toString();

Comment: @MarcusRey That is strange.  Can you add your rugbycounter.xml file to the question?

Comment: I've added the layout file. It is strange that it crashes on the screen rotation of the home/main fragment but none of the others.

Comment: @MarcusRey Make sure that the EditText references aren't null in onCreateView()

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you show me an example of how to make sure the edittext references are not null? Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusRey I just updated the answer with null check code

Comment: Alternatively you can also use the findViewById inside onActivityCreated method in your fragment class. @MarcusRey
Sample code http://hastebin.com/uladexonag.coffee

Comment: @HarshitDwivedi That sample would not work for this case, as it's looking for a layout ID from the Activity.

Comment: @DanielNugent will it work if he adds the fragment to the rugbyCounter.xml via xml?

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the null check code but the app is still crashing with the same error. It's a head scratcher! :-/

Comment: @MarcusRey If you don't get the Toasts then the EditText fields are not null in onCreateView(), so that is good.  Make sure that you're using the member variables everywhere, make sure that you're not accidentally creating any local variables.  Basically, make sure that the only place you have `EditText teamAname` declared is at the top in the class difinition.

Comment: @HarshitDwivedi It actually would work to call `getActivity().findViewById()` in `onActivityCreated()` as long as the Fragment's layout was properly inflated in `onCreateView()` and added to the view tree.  However, there's really no reason to over-complicate it, as it's cleaner to just use `findViewById()` directly on the view.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385461/findviewbyid-returning-null-in-fragment